# Custom template not working with the following options

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I followed this tutorial for the page specific template  -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Created a page through wordpress admin panel - `Blog Page` URL like -- `http://localhost/wordpress/blog-page/` and set template to my template "Swapnesh" from the admin panel itself.

Created my specific page template as `page-blog-page.php` containing following code --

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Swapnesh
*/


get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="contentabc" style="border:7px solid red;">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now when im navigating to `http://mysite/wordpress/blog-page/` im not getting that border so that i can proceed further, let me know what im doing wrong.

**note**-- Under "`Reading Settings`" mu post page selection was "Blog Page" when i dis select this option its showing me the `red border` but no posts then :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you've solved this yet but I think the problem relates to the belt and braces approach you've ended up with here. By naming your custom template page-blog-page.php it should negate the need to explicitly assign it as a custom template for a page with the slug blog-page.

Try changing the name of the custom template completely - my-template.php - to see what happens. I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: i really dont know how :( but changing the name clicks for me (although i think i have not done any thing wrong with the naming convention)

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected Swapnesh as page template While creating new page ?
You can select it from right side Page Attributes.

Comment: already mentioned -- " set template to my template "Swapnesh" from the admin panel itself. " :(

Comment: @swapnesh Is it live ? can i have link ?